# DatePicker OnSelect event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, form-submit, onselect

I try to submit a form called 'cobro2' just after select the date in a datepicker field with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#datecobro').datePicker({
        clickInput:true,
        startDate: '01-01-2000',
        onSelect: function () {$('#cobro2').submit();}
        });
});
</script>
```

Whats happend?

Comment: can you make a fiddle on this

Comment: cobro2 is a class or id

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh Kumar Ganesh , sorry, I can't understand you

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AkBUv/351/

Answer (score 0):

issue is uppercase `P` in `datePicker` change it to lowercase `p` as below:

```
 $('#datecobro').datepicker({
     .......//-------^--------this lowercase p is required.
 });
```

---

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/voqojoja/1/edit)

Comment: which datepicker you are using. jquery ui or bootstrap's??

Comment: @user3811413 you should go to the documentation then, i don't know if the demo added solves the issue or not. As you mentioned your jquery ui version, so for now i suggest you to update your jquery library to 1.10+ too. Check out the demo if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
form id not declare.

[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AkBUv/353/)`enter code here`